# ApexCharts barchart grouping the series of dataset per year on VueJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, vuejs2, apexcharts

I am mapping a dataset that is from an API request, and with the following data I have grouped it by **year**. Under the specific year, it has object values with **total enrollees**, **academic year**, and **academic semester**. Finally, it would somehow look like this sample bar graph below:

[image: sample group by year bar graph]

I have already looked at the documentation [ApexChart Distributed Columns](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/column-charts/distributed/), and have some issues on how to implement it the same as the required bar graph on top.

Comment: please, read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or the whole series on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on StackOverflow - and update your question accordingly. Don't post screenshots of data in your question - nobody would want to type in that in order to help you out.

Comment: Thanks mate, my bad I should have read the whole documentation for how to ask a question.  I'll update my question right away.

Comment: just suggestions: you get much more help if you give support to the potential helpers :) the less time someone needs to replicate your problem, the more people will try to give you answers. Unfortunately (but understandably), providing data as images is a blocker for most.

Comment: Thanks mate, hoping I can resolve this issue and get back to the community  somehow.